# update manager Failed to download repository information+

Tags: update-manager

whenever I try to cheek for updates the following error turns up:

```
W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
, W:Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/sun-java-community-team/sun-java6/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this ppas are not on. Try to go to this links and you'll see they are offline; You may want to have java from another repository. :(